# Making this ActiveRecord lookups more efficient

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to get an array of all email addresses for users of certain service types.

Using a string of ActiveRecord has_many relations, I can get these like this:

```
affected_services = Service.where(service_type: 'black')
affected_accounts = affected_services.map {|s| s.account}
affected_emails = affected_accounts.map {|a| a.contact.email}
```

I know it would be a fairly simple SQL query, but I'd prefer to see if ActiveRecord can do it to keep database abstraction.

Is there a good ActiveRecord way to retrieve those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :include to include children in the query.

```
Account.find(:all, :include => :contact, :conditions => {:service_id => Service.where(:service_type => 'black').map{|account| account.contact.email } })
```

Comment: That doesn't sort out the issue unfortunately, `emails` is not an attribute of `Account`, `Account` belongs_to `Contact`, `Contact` has a field `email`.

Comment: Just include contact instead, and map its email property. I edited my answer, does that help?